# Bevel edges of a box without cuts on corners

Tags: edges, bevel

I'm trying to bevel the edges of a box, **folded based on a die cut**. *(It is not a normal cube!)* Any ideas how to get rid of these little spiky cuts at the corner? Is there a better solution for this problem? Thanks a lot guys, I'm a bloody beginner.

[image: Little cuts on the corner of a box, made by beveled edges.]

// Edit:

Ist comes from a folded die cut (plane with solidify mod.) with this shape:

[image: upper part of die cut]

It looks like this before bevel:

[image: Before bevel]

Comment: You need to give us some more information, preferably what's the geometry before the bevel is applied, you probably have some topological errors that cause issues there… Here's how a bevel works on the default cube: https://i.imgur.com/IwIQNle.png and icosphere: https://i.imgur.com/zmfvyE1.png Even on some random geometry, while it looks bad, it doesn't have as big discontinuities as in yours: https://i.imgur.com/sdInxWm.png Try in Edit mode: A, M, B keys to remove doubles, shift+N to recalculate normals.

Comment: I added an image of the die cut, wich is folded together in the first image. The geometry should be quit simple.

Comment: I think a more reasonable approach is to make the beveled figure first, then unfold it. Then you can unwrap using e.g. [Paper Model](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/import_export/paper_model.html) addon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqDGwpNEmy8 or

Comment: This is a real die cut for a real product. In the end it has to look exactly like the box looks in the real world. I'm not free to make something up by my own, unfortunately.